# Setup a different password for windows logon and for administratively allow software(s) to install

Tags: windows, password-protection

I am using a pc running windows7 at workplace it has a logon password set-up which everyone knows and they install different softwares which sometimes crashes the window and it is very hectic for me to repeatedly install windows every time.
Then I set up a local policy on every software i.e. if a user want to install a software .exe it asks admin password but as you know if some one already knows about logon password then he/she can install software using logon password.

It is done using local security policy tool which is found at control panel and User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode.

What I want to do is to separate these two passwords i.e. logon password should be different from the password which grants access for software installation on desktop pc. If anyone knows I would be thankful!

Comment: I would create an admin user just to install and update software and one (or more) non-admin users to work on the computer. Every user account with a different password, though.

Comment: I know this but it will become very troublesome for me to every-time change accounts when so many people using a single pc for internet purpose. Thanks for the suggestion @TobyU. Could this not possible?

Comment: Why not just use Active Directory?